# HMAC-SHA256 in Java produces different output than JavaScript

Tags: java, sha256, hmac

I've been trying to port some NodeJS code to Java in order to make HMAC signed requests to an API. I've been able to simplify the code to a point were encoding is clearly affecting the output.

Here's my code in JavaScript:

```js
var APIKey = "secret";
var secretByteArray = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(APIKey);
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256("Message", secretByteArray);
var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
//alert(hashInBase64);
document.write(hashInBase64);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/enc-base64.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/hmac-sha256.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

Here's the Java Code:

```
try {
        String secret = "secret";
        String message = "Message";

        byte[] secretByteArray = Base64.getEncoder().encode(secret.getBytes());

        //byte[] secretByteArray = Base64.encodeBase64(secret.getBytes("utf-8"), true);

        Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(secretByteArray, "HmacSHA256");
        sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);

        String hash = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(message.getBytes()));
        System.out.println(hash);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
```

If I don't encode to base64 the "secret" I get the same output, but I'd like to get the same result with encoded strings. I suspect the encoded byte arrays have padding or sign differences.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your Java code uses `Base64.getEncoder().encode` to convert *to* Base64.

Your JavaScript code uses `CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse` to convert *from* Base64.

You need to make those match.